# Proper way to pack a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, bit-packing

What is the correct way to pack a five-byte asci string into python so that it is 8-bytes and little endian? For example, something like:

```
from struct import pack
pack('<ccccc3x', 'David')
```

Or:

```
pack('<ccccc3x', b'D', b'a', b'v', b'i', b'd')
# this works but seems unreadable to me
```

What would be the correct (or simplest) way to do this? Ideally, something like:

```
>>> pack('<ccccc3x', *bytearray(b'David'))
```

But it seems I cannot pass a list or do variable-unpacking and I have to do a new positional argument for every character.

---

The best I can come up with is the following, but I'm hoping there's a better way to do it:

```
# why won't it allow me to use `c`(har) and only `b`(yte) ?
>>> pack('<5b3x', *bytearray(b'David'))
b'David\x00\x00\x00'
```

---

**Update**: seems like this might be the best way:

```
>>> pack('<5s3x', b'David')
b'David\x00\x00\x00'
```

Not sure though about all the different 'char'-ish types: `s`, `b`, and `c` from the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/struct.html) page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Endianness only is a thing for values more than a byte in size, so you don't need to worry about it here.

The most succinct way I can think of to pad a 5-byte bytestring to 8 bytes is

```
b'David'.ljust(8, b'\0')
```

Comment: Really neat solution

Comment: @AKX that's a great idea! I actually was doing the `pack` because I had a large bytearray and I was just appending/extending values to it, but yea for a asci-string I think this is much better.